# Writing Windows GUI applications with embedded Python scripts

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

What would be the optimal way to develop a basic graphical application for Windows based on a Python console script? It would be great if the solution could be distributed as a standalone directory, containing the `.exe` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to write a graphical windows application in Python, to do this I suggest using wxPython and then py2exe to create a standalone exe that can run on any machine without requiring python to be installed

The following tutorial shows everything step by step: [Quickly Creating Professional
Looking Application Using wxPython, py2exe and InnoSetup](http://www.osdc.org.il/2006/html/quickly_creating_professional_looking_application_using_wxpython_py2exe_and_innosetup.pdf)

Comment: @Diaa Thanks, looks like what I need, diving in.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you use IronPython, which is Microsoft's implementation of Python for the .NET framework.

Answer (score 2):

[Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) is quick and easy to use. Tkinter is in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

[Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) is the best solution to achieve the goal mentioned.

After creating the app in Tkinter one can convert it into a cross-platform executable using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)